# Share mocks across test files

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

I want to share a mock implementation across tests files, but I don't want to mock globally the module. I don't need to mock the module by default, but in some cases I want to apply the same mocking logic across files.

```
jest.mock('some-module', () => {
   //... long mock implementation
})
```

I didn't find a way to modularize jest mocks, I already tried the following techniques, which don't work

```
// sharedMocks.js
export const mockSomeModule = () => {
    jest.mock('some-module', () => { /* ... */ })
}

// from other file
import { mockSomeModule } from '../sharedMocks'
mockSomeModule()
```

or

```
// sharedMocks.js
export const someModuleMock = () => {
    //... long mock implementation
}

// from other file
import { someModuleMock } from '../sharedMocks'
jest.mock('some-module', someModuleMock)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, the directory structure like this:

```sh
.
├── main.spec.ts
├── main.ts
├── other.spec.ts
├── other.ts
├── sharedMocks.ts
└── someModule.ts
```

`someModule.ts`:

```js
function findById() {
  return 'real data by id';
}

function findByName() {
  return 'real data by name';
}

export { findById, findByName };
```

`main.ts` use `someModule.ts`:

```js
import { findById } from './someModule';

function main() {
  return findById();
}

export { main };
```

`other.ts` use `someModule.ts`:

```js
import { findByName } from './someModule';

function other() {
  return findByName();
}

export { other };
```

`sharedMocks.ts`, mock `someModule`:

```js
const findById = jest.fn();

export { findById };
```

`main.spec.ts`, use `sharedMocks`

```js
import * as someModule from './sharedMocks';
import { main } from './main';

jest.mock('./someModule.ts', () => someModule);

describe('test suites A', () => {
  it('t1', () => {
    someModule.findById.mockReturnValueOnce('mocked data');
    const actualValue = main();
    expect(actualValue).toBe('mocked data');
  });
});
```

`other.spec.ts`, don't use `sharedMocks`

```js
import { other } from './other';

describe('other', () => {
  it('t1', () => {
    const actualValue = other();
    expect(actualValue).toBe('real data by name');
  });
});
```