# Vitest - Share mock between test files

Tags: reactjs, vite, react-testing-library, vitest

I have a problem with my mocks in Vitest. My app use a big component library (MUI) which take a lot of time to mock if I use `vi.importActual`. As I frequently mock the same components, I would like to have a common mock to be used in all tests but I can't find how to declare it as Vitest initialize its mock before importing dependencies.

When I try to execute the tests, I have the following error:

> Error: [vitest] There was an error when mocking a module. If you are using "vi.mock" factory, make sure there are no top level variables inside, since this call is hoisted to top of the file. Read more: https://vitest.dev/api/vi.html#vi-mock

I found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43292263/share-mocks-across-test-files) with the same issue but using Jest. The solution doesn't seem to work for Vitest.

You can a find a reproduction case [in this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/vitest-mutualize-mocks-t3dw22?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.test.tsx%3A19%2C5-19%2C51).

App.jsx

```
import { Button } from "@mui/material"

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Button>Test</Button>
    )
}
```

mockedLibrary.jsx

```
const mockedLibrary = {
    Button: vi.fn().mockImplementation((props: any) => <button className="mockedButton" {...props} />),
};

export default mockedLibrary
```

App.test.jsx

```
import mockedLibrary from "./mockedLibrary";

describe("App tests", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    /*
    I want to avoid this kind of mock

    vi.mock("@mui/material", async () => ({
        ...((await vi.importActual("@mui/material"))),
      Button: vi.fn().mockImplementation((props: any) => <button className="mockedButton" {...props} />),
    }));
    */

    // This mock doesn't work
    vi.mock("@mui/material", () => mockedLibrary);
  });

  it (...)

})
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround. I am not calling it *a solution* but it seems to work fine.

This work around relies on [`vi.doMock`](https://vitest.dev/api/vi.html#vi-domock) and [dynamic imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import), here is how you can use it:

1. create your mocks in a separate file

```
export const mockModuleA = (params) => {
  vi.doMock('module-a', () => {
    return { /* your mock, some might require a `default` key */ }
    /*
    here are some examples
    return { default: vi.fn() }
    return { fetchProducts: () => [{}, {}] }
    */
  })
}
```

2. From your test file, import your mock

```
import {mockModuleA} from './mocks'

describe('component being tested', () => {
  it('works', async () => {
    mockModuleA()
    const { default: ComponentBeingTested } = await import('component-being-tested')
    render(<ComponentBeingTested />)
    
    // inside codeBeingTested, the moduleA should be mocked
  })
})
```

You might need to use `vi.resetModules()` when you are testing conditions in your code.

Hope it works!